# Where to fetch data in React when I have a reusable react component, Parent or Child component (reusable component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying a react-redux-form in my application. I have made a component which sets the layout and every individual form component calls this component and passes the children which are the various form elements. And now this form is being included in my other components. Every form has some metadata to be fetched to show it in the form. Now my question is whether to fetch all the data in my main component or the individual form component.

Following is the hierarchy in which the components are being called:

**Page Component --> Individual Form Component --> Form Layout Component**

Whether the form metadata API call should be in Page component or in Individual Form component.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not necessary. You are fond of calling meta data from where you are comfortable. If you use Redux then you can use `connect` to access the store.

Comment: Generally it is said that data should be fetched in parent component, why that theory then?